# Join 4 Tables to find total and sort by total

Tags: mysql

i have 3 tables

1) users

2) user_likes

3) user_pictures

4) user_pucture_likes

```
users(id, name)
user_likes(id, user_id, like)
user_pictures(id, user_id, filename)
user_picture_likes(id, user_picture_id, like)
```

what i am trying to do is to sort the user on the total like on user_like + user_picture_like

I am not good with joining more than 2 tables.

i got upto here

```
SELECT t2.user_id, sum(t1.total_likes) as image_likes from user_pictures as t2 JOIN (
        SELECT sum(like_status) as total_likes, user_picture_id FROM `user_picture_likes` GROUP BY user_picture_id ORDER BY total_likes DESC
)as t1 
ON t1.user_picture_id = t2.id GROUP BY t2.user_id ORDER BY image_likes DESC
```

and how do i proceed from here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT T1.Id AS UserID, SUM(T2.like), Tmp.filename AS Image, Tmp.Imageslikes
FROM users T1
LEFT JOIN user_likes T2 ON T1.Id = T2.user_id 
LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT T3.user_id, T3.filename, SUM(T4.likes) Imageslikes
       FROM user_pictures LEFT JOIN user_picture_likes T4 ON T3.Id = T4.user_picture_id
       GROUP BY T3.user_id, T3.filename
)Tmp ON T1.Id = Tmp.user_id
```